# Laravel Schedule Not Running

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I'm having an issue with Laravel's scheduler. It's setup properly, the command is correct as I can run it from the terminal, but it doesn't work at all. The CRON job is correct as far as I know as it does show up with `sudo service cron status`

But `php artisan schedule:run` says nothing is queued. My Kernel.php is as follows

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
      'App\Console\Commands\ResetBars',
      'App\Console\Commands\ResetUsers',
      'App\Console\Commands\UpdateBars',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('reset:bars')->hourlyAt(1);
        $schedule->command('reset:users')->daily();
        //$schedule->command('update:bars')->dailyAt('8:00');
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I have a slack log at the end of the command (which I've verified works) and it isn't sending anything hourlyAt(1) so it should've JUST ran at 8:01 but it didn't.

Anyone have any thoughts on why it isn't running? Is it getting queued and just not running?

This is in the cron tab

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * php ~/var/www/BarhopAPI/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Thanks

- Zach

Comment: Can you post the conjob command?

Comment: How do I get this? I put what's in the CRON tab in the question now

Comment: `crontab -l` - just copy the line with your projects directory in it

Comment: Okay so I think I found the issue then. I just ran this command `* * * * * php ~/var/www/MyFolder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` but afterwards did crontab -l and it says, "no crontab for root"

Comment: oh. I didn't add it to the crontab. ugh, stupid question with stupid answers. Let me google how to add it.

Comment: Edit: It did not work @devk. My crontab -l is in my above

Comment: You probably have to remove `~` (shorthand for your home directory) from the folder path. But you can check what your directory is by going to the project and typing `pwd`. Copy that path.

Comment: Okay will report back.

Comment: Yup that did it

Answer (score 2):

Okay so the steps I followed to make sure I did it right

`crontab -l` from @devk, thank you so much for that

To add a crontab job to your Laravel install it's `crontab -e`, then when prompted for what type (if your first time setting it up) hit `2` to go to nano, then paste the following after the asterisks

`* * * * * php /var/www/Laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Obviously replacing the `/var/www/Laravel` with the path to your Laravel install

Edit: That did not work.
Edit2: @devk helped me fix it, needed to remove the `~`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while setting a CRON job

> I was using  **"dailyAt()"** to run the CRON,  Actually, my CRON was
>   running but the timezone is not own mine. Please go and check your
>   **"config/app.php"** and **check your timezone** (I just changed my timezone
>   to 'Asia/Kolkata')

To test your CRON please comment the scheduler inside your schedule() method and add a new schedule (***This step will help you to check your CRON is working or not*** )

```
$schedule->command('jobexp:warning')->cron('* * * * *');

php artisan schedule:run
```

Please ensure that your CRON is working